# MYSQL Weird behaviour in grouping

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have transactions table with a description column. While testing, I observed an unusual behaviour.
There were not completely similar descriptions `"Circle K Skövde"` and `"Circle K Skovde"` in different transactions. When I ran group_by query, I could not find the description with `"Circle K Skövde"` but only `"Circle K Skovde"` transactions.
So I added another filter of amount where amount was from the transaction with `"Circle K Skövde"` description and this time it returned correct description.

My application runs on Ruby on Rails framework and uses MYSQL database. First I thought, this is due to Rails but in MYSQL workbench, it is behaving same way. It means MYSQL is the culprit.

Below is the SQL query:

```
    SELECT 
    SUM(`Transaction`.`amount`) AS sum_amount,
    `Transaction`.`original_description` collate utf8mb3_bin transaction_original_description,
    `Transaction`.`category_id` AS transaction_category_id,
    CAST(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(`Transaction`.`transaction_at`,
                        '+00:00',
                        'Etc/UTC'),
                '%Y-%m-01')
        AS DATE) AS cast_date_format_convert_tz_transaction_transaction_at_00_00_etc_utc_y_m_01_as_date
FROM
    `Transaction`
        INNER JOIN
    `Account` ON `Account`.`id` = `Transaction`.`account_id`
        INNER JOIN
    `Provider` ON `Provider`.`id` = `Account`.`provider_id_id`
        INNER JOIN
    `UserDetail` ON `UserDetail`.`id` = `Provider`.`user_detail_id`
        INNER JOIN
    `categories` ON `categories`.`id` = `Transaction`.`category_id`
        INNER JOIN
    `categories` `parents_categories` ON `parents_categories`.`id` = `categories`.`parent_category_id`
WHERE
    `UserDetail`.`raw_response_id` = 'cf0cc9dfb9dd481d8682e7a41e8c3068'
        AND (transaction_at >= '2022-11-01 00:00:00')
        AND `parents_categories`.`transaction_type` = 'expenses'
        AND `parents_categories`.`parent_category_id` IS NULL
        AND `Transaction`.`id` != 'mysql_temporary_query_fix'
        AND (`Transaction`.`transaction_at` >= '2022-11-01 00:00:00'
        AND `Transaction`.`transaction_at` <= '2023-11-01 09:24:39.198035')
GROUP BY `Transaction`.`original_description` , `Transaction`.`category_id` , CAST(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(`Transaction`.`transaction_at`,
                    '+00:00',
                    'Etc/UTC'),
            '%Y-%m-01')
    AS DATE);
```

Is there any solution to this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably a collation issue. When you do the group by you must be using a collation that cannot distinguish between the accented and unaccented versions of the same character.

Comment: Check your session and table collation settings. Depends on the collation your values are equal or not: https://dbfiddle.uk/3x6a6G2Q Specify needed collation in the query if you're not sure that session settings are correct.

Comment: Yes this is a collation issue. When ran query with COLLATE utf8mb4_bin, it is giving correct results.  Now finding a way to, use COLLATE with rails ORM. Please suggest if you know something about it.

Comment: @AdityaGadekar please post the SQL you intend to run and we can help you convert this into Arel for the purposes of rails ORM. For instance: `Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation('COLLATE',MyModel.arel_table[:description],Arel.sql('utf8mb4_bin'))` will generate `my_models.description COLLATE utf8mb4_bin`

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, this is caused by the collation setting.

“Skövde” and “Skovde” are different words so they treated separately.

It is hard to comment on the query result as you have not shown the query itself nor the sample dataset but, in general, make sure that the collation settings make sense across all the elements - server settings (server, database, table, column) and client settings (RoR).